# geom_text from separate file outside of initial plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following two dataframes

```
df <- data.frame(Groesse=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  x=c(0, 1, 30, 25),
                  y=c(0, 90, 85, 20))


df_text <- data.frame(Groesse=c("X", "Y"),
                 x=c(1, 30),
                 y=c(105, 105))
```

and tried to achieve what I want with the following:

```
plot <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_text(data = df_text, aes(x, y, label = "Groesse")) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0)) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(10, 1, 1, 1), "lines"))

plot
```

I would like to have the annotations (using `geom_text()`) to be above the scatterplot, but outside of the plot area. However, my plot is missing the values from `geom_text()`.

[image: Plot without text]

Desired output (just a sketch):

[image: Desired Output]

Any idea how I can add the text outside the plot area without producing two different plots and then combining those in a grid?

Comment: Added a sketch (I don't have a proper graphics program on my work laptop, unfortunately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to turning clipping off in the co-ordinates function, you need to set the out-of-bounds `oob` argument in `scale_y_continuous()` so the data isn't censored.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(data = df_text, aes(x, y, label = "Groesse")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0), oob = ~ .x) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(10, 1, 1, 1), "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 2):

This is just to point out an alternative to using `geom_text()` for annotations. For continuous axes, you can use the secondary axis to add some annotations.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Groesse=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 x=c(0, 1, 30, 25),
                 y=c(0, 90, 85, 20))


df_text <- data.frame(Groesse=c("X", "Y"),
                      x=c(1, 30),
                      y=c(105, 105))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      ~.x, name = NULL, breaks = c(1, 30),
      labels = rep("Groesse", 2)
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.length.x.top = unit(0, "pt"),
    axis.text.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ritchie Sacramento is ideal in this case.

However if you need further customisation you may want to use the [`gridExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html) package to create two plots and place one on top of the other:

```r
p1  <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y))
p2  <- ggplot(df_text) + 
    geom_text(
        aes(x, y, label = "Groesse")
    ) +
    ylim(c(100, 110)) +
    xlim(c(0, 30)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()
    )

library(gridExtra)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p2, p1, ncol=1, heights = c(1,4))
```

[image]

Comment: I would need the text to be outside of the rectangle, and I also need the gridlines (in my proper plot, which has a bit more complicated data)